# matlab simple for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have 200 rows of data and I am trying to extract specific numbers from column 3 which relate to either 1, 2, 3, or 4, (repeated randomly) in column 1.

I can get those numbers in column 3 relating to 1 in column 1 by using

```
E=C(C(:,1)==1,[3]);
```

so I assumed I could extract all those relating to 1 then to 2 then to 3 then to 4 by using this loop

```
for i=1:4;

E=C(C(:,1)==i,[3]);

end
```

but all I get is the data relating to all the 4s in column 1. If I change it to 1:3 I get data relating to the 3s. I've tried writing it with
`for i=[1,2,3,4]`
but, again just get the numbers from column 3 relating to the 4s in column 1.

I'm sure it's a simple error but any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the value of `E` each time through the loop, so at the end you're just left with the last iteration.

If you aren't guaranteed to have the same number of results each time through the loop (e.g. there are different numbers of `1`s and `2`s in the original data), you can use a cell array to store the outputs:

```
for i=1:4;

    E{i}=C(C(:,1)==i,[3]);

end
```

To access the result of the first iteration of the loop (`i==1`), use `E{1}` (and so on for the other values).

The above approach will let you access the results from each iteration separately. If you later decide you just want a single matrix with the results from all of these iterations combined, you can use

```
cell2mat(E)
```

to convert to an array of all the values.

Comment: Thanks. This works quite well. However, as, in fact, there are a different number of results each time through the loop, can't convert to array of all the values.  Get message Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
 Thanks. Might have to work around the fact that E{1} contains more

Comment: Got this to work by going back to original set of data, before excluding 'null' trials, so that each column is same size to be able to convert cell2matrix.  Now have extra column (from original data) to identify nulls and should be able to continue.  Thanks.

Comment: In fact, I tried this with E{i}=C(C(:,1)==i,[3,4]); to make sure the results were the same size and also to allow me to see, from column 4, which of the data to remove by making it NaN.  Got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a for loop to test which numbers in the 3th column in C match a particular number. I'd use:

```
C = randi(10,[200,4]); %example matrix 200x4 with integers 1-10
idx = ismember(C(:,3),[1 2 3 4]); %get indices
numbers = C(idx,3); %get numbers in C matrix
```

**Edit 1:**

Do you mean something like this? It gets the index of column 1,2 and 4 that contains any number 1-4, if that the case it returns the value of the 3th column.

```
idx = ismember(C(:,[1 2 4]),[1 2 3 4]); %get indices
numbers = C(any(idx),3); %get numbers in C matrix
```

**Edit 2:**

```
C=[2 586 339; 2 148 1283; 3 427 356; 1 234 476; 1 301 456; 4 235 347; 4 229 587; 3 156 438]

for k=1:4
%or add a for loop if you want the numbers of column 2 and 3 separately
   C(C(:,1)==k,2:3)  
end

ans =

   234   476
   301   456


ans =

   586    339
   148   1283


ans =

   427   356
   156   438


ans =

   235   347
   229   587
```

Comment: This was not quite what I wanted, it only takes the nos. 1, 2, 3 and 4 out of column 3 but I wanted a set of nos. in column 3 that related to the nos. 1, 2, 3 and 4 in another column.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: [1 2 4] actually needed to be [1 2 3] otherwise exceeded matrix dimentsions but the code only produced the first 2 rows in the column. Also played around with it but still no luck. But thanks - good experience for me.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem, with an example how your data looks like and what the output should be?

Comment: I have something like:

Comment: Sorry, I have a matrix say [2 586 339; 2 148 1283; 3 427 356; 1 234 476; 1 301 456; 4 235 347; 4 229 587; 3 156 438] and from this I want to extract [301 234]',[586 148]', [427 156]',[235 229]' to get all the data relating to 1 in the first column, then 2, then 3, then 4 and then the same for the data in third column of the original matrix.  My actual data has 216 rows. I'm an absolute beginner so sorry if I'm not explaining correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
E = C(ismember(C(:,1),[1 2 3 4]),3)
```

**Edit 1:**

```
C(~ismember(C(:,1),[1 2 3 4]),:)=[];
[~,y1] = sort(C(:,1));
E = C(y1,3)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this spat out the whole of column 3 as it originally was so not quite what I wanted.

Comment: @user3560490 Check out **Edit 1**.

Comment: Got the same as before but this time with square brackets around each number.  Played around with it a bit but didn't get four columns

Comment: @user3560490 So you want four separate columns for `1` to `4` matches right? If so, you must understand that some might have empty cells because number of matches would differ across them.

Comment: Yes, that seems the main problem. Just mentioned to @tmpearce that I have gone back to original data and now incuding some that will have to be removed later for sake of getting a useful matrix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain elements corresponding to `1`,  `2`, etc separately: use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray(C(:,1),C(:,3),[],@(x) {x});
```

With this approach, `result{1}` contains all elements of column `3` for which column `1` is `1`, `result{2}` contains all elements of column `3` for which column `1` is `2`, etc. The elements may not be in their original order.

Comment: This is good but I kinda need them in the original order.  Might be able to use this on something else. Thanks